# Firebase Password Validation allowed regex

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if anyone knew the official allowed passwords for Firebase's Email and Password Authentication API.

So far I understand that there is

- a minimum of 6 characters required
- a-z allowed
- A-Z allowed
- 0-9 allowed
- special characters allowed ~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=|}]{["':;?/>.<,
- white spaces allowed

If this is the case, would the regex for validation on my side just be `{6,}` ? (alternatively I could just check the length of the field)

EDIT: I assume it's similar to [Google's normal password requirements](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en) but only requiring 6 characters instead of 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your understanding is correct - the only requirement is a minimum of 6 chars.

However, if you are building Android/iOS apps, I would suggest -not- to hardcode the validation logic in your app, since the new user signup request is handled by Firebase Auth server.

Comment: Good point, I will let the response "error" from createUserWithEmail display the alert/message back if the password is invalid.

Comment: What is the maximum allowable password length?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a regular expression to validate password before sending to firebase.

I suggest to use this pattern as it pass as `minimum` qualifications! also firebase verify and validate password after you send it too Firebase cloud... so keep it simple.

```swift
let pattern: String = "(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]).{6,}"
```

1. Minimum 6 character: `{6,}`
2. Any character allowed: `(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])`

> Remember, it is just the minimum requirements for a valid password, you can choose how strong the password should be based on your software.

Comment: I use `(?=.*[0-9]+)(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[A-Z]+).{6,}` (test it in action: https://regexr.com/620qv)

Comment: my pattern is short hand for yours @PsychoX

Comment: @PsychoX regex in your comment does not match if you don't include a number (e.g. `Helloo9` is matched but `Hellooo` is not), but the one in the answer matches both.

Comment: Its not shorthand. The pattern I provided REQUIRES at least one digit and at least one big and small character.