# Unity Firebase Authentication - invalid password

Tags: firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine

In the Firebase docs, the following is stated regarding one of the functions:

CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync

System.Threading.Tasks.Task< FirebaseUser > CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(
string email,
string password
)

Creates, and on success, logs in a user with the given email address and password.

An error is returned when account creation is unsuccessful (due to another existing account, invalid password, etc.).

---

While setting up a Firebase authentication flow in my Unity project, my friend and I discovered a weird error - specifically, an "invalid password" error when trying to register with the following details:

email: asdf@asdf.com
password: asdf

But, when we changed the password to Asdf1234, the error went away and the user was perfectly registered in our Firebase console.

This seems to imply that there are some passwords that are invalid, and some that are valid (like the documentation suggests). Is there any way to find out which passwords are valid and which aren't? This information would help us convey to users what passwords they can choose.

Thanks

As mentioned, we tried tried many things (like updating our google-json, running the code on the main thread, etc.) but the only thing that actually worked was changing the password from "asdf" to "Asdf1234" so I'd appreciate some elaboration on what passwords can actually be used.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Password Validation allowed regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064248/firebase-password-validation-allowed-regex)

This link seems to cover it pretty well, but I'd like to know where this information is officially available, so if anyone knows, please comment.